# Clock in PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I know I can insert in PowerPoint a clock via Insert > Date & Time; but this adds the clock in a fixed position, on the bottom towards the left. Is there a way to insert it in another place?

I know I can manually move it, but that would mean to manually move it slide by slide, so I was looking for a more automated way.

I'm using PowerPoint2019.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a flash clock(external) and can position it as per your requirement. There are various options of clock such as timer, real time etc which you can download and insert in your powerpoint slide.

Comment: Can you insert it in all the slide at once, in the position you need? I can move the Intert > Date & Time field where I want, the issue is that I have to do it manually in each slide.

Comment: you can try it, I am on linux, can't test and tell

Answer (score 0):

The clock inserted in the PPT will only be fixed in the lower left corner.

It is a by-design behavior.

We had to manually move it to another location.